# How to use ForEach controller on an array?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

jmeter ForEach controller can be used to iterate over variables with same prefix like,

```
myVar_1
myVar_2
myVar_3
```

But in my case input variable is array of strings, `[ "val1", "val2", "val3" ]` How to iterate over an array and send separate request for each value?

Comment: Are you extracting the array from the response?

Comment: Yes. I am extracting array from response by applying JSON Path extractor on response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to feed this [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) to the ForEach Controller, but you can **convert** it into a form which can be understood by the ForEach Controller

1. Add a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) after the variable holding this JSON Array is defined
2. Put the following code into the "Script" area:

   ```
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get("yourInputVariable"))
   def counter = 1
   json.each {
       vars.put("myVar_" + counter, it)
       counter++
   }
   ```

   Replace `yourInputVariable` with the actual name of the variable holding the JSON Array
3. Add ForEach Controller under the JSR223 Sampler and perform "normal" configuration as you would do it for `myVar_1, myVar_2,...` - it will work fine as JSR223 Sampler creates the relevant variables basing on the data from the JSON Array.

See [Parsing and producing JSON - Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) articles for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Same way as you use for same prefixed variables.

For variable `myVar`

```
myVar = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
//Following variables are automatically created
myVar_1 = "val1";
myVar_2 = "val2";
myVar_3 = "val3";
```

ForEach controller will be used on `myVar_1, myVar_2, myVar_3`

Use **Debug Sampler** to ensure.

jmeter version : 3.1 r1770033

Answer (score 0):

I tried Dmitri's answer, but basically got stuck with the *groovy* script as it works only for a simple array of strings. I, however, needed a more complex array of JSON objects.
Then I switched the scripting language to *ecmascript* and based on the original script wrote a good old JS like this:

```
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(vars.get("ReportSources"));
    for(var index = 0; index < jsonObject.length; index++) {
        vars.put("rs_" + (index + 1), JSON.stringify(jsonObject[index]));
    }
```

It worked for me.